# Create NuGet package for an entire solution

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a nuget package that contains my "starter project". This is a project which I use to start every Umbraco project.

This starter project has the following structure:

```
Solution:
    Umbraco project
    CustomControls project
```

In short, I want Nuget to:

```
1) download a specific version of Umbraco, and put it in the Umbraco project folder
2) Add the CustomControls project
```

I can put the CustomControls project in the "Content"-folder, but I can't get the Umbraco project in my solution at the top level. Right now, NuGet seems to create this:

```
Solution:
  Umbraco project => CustomControls project
```

So the CustomControls project is inside the Umbraco project, which doesn't serve my purpose as it has to remain separate.

So two seperate projects inside one solution.
How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameters in Install.ps1 is called $project, and it is a reference to the EnvDTE Project object for the project into which your package has been installed.  You should be able to call DTE.Solution.AddFromFile() to add another project to the solution.